# Use existing XML Schema type definitions in pattern restriction

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I am creating an XML Schema for an existing XML format. The schema is based on the code that already produces the XML, and example output.

Is there a way to use existing data types in a pattern restriction?

### Example one

The date is coded in the existing XML format as YYYYMMDD (e.g. "20210308"). This does not match the existing [XML Schema date type definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#date) which uses YYYY-MM-DD (e.g. "2021-03-08"). The best way to define the type then seems to be a string with a pattern restriction. Can I refer to other types in the pattern, such as [gYear](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#gYear) or [yearFrag](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#nt-yrFrag)? That would let me write

```
<xs:pattern value="&yearFrag;&monthFrag;&dayFrag;" />
```

instead of

```
<xs:pattern value="-?([1-9][0-9]{3,}|0[0-9]{3})(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])" />
```

Is this possible? What's the best way to define this type?

### Example two

There is a string coded in the XML format that contains a previously defined custom simple type. Can I refer to that in the new pattern?

Example first type:

```
<xs:simpleType name="myCustomId">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:pattern value="m[0-5]t[0-9]{0,10}" />
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Example of intended re-use:

```
<xs:simpleType name="idBasedName">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:pattern value="export_&myCustomId;_[crs]\.csv" />
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Is this possible? What's the best way to define this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Can I refer to other types in the pattern, such as gYear or yearFrag?

No, the XML Schema regex subset is defined here: https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#regexs
It does not include any special support for fragments of the XSD grammar.

> > There is a string coded in the XML format that contains a previously defined custom simple type. Can I refer to that in the new pattern?

I cannot do any better than this: https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#rf-pattern
Note especially the section with title 'Multiple patterns'

Comment: Too bad it's not possible, but thanks for confirming. The rules regarding how multiple patterns are combined were informative, thanks again.